# ASP Control for large Lists replacing DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am using asp .net 3.5 including Ajax Control Toolkit.

So currently I am using an asp DropDownList to realize a simple Selection of one element, but the List grew over time and now contains over ten thousands elements which causes usability and performance problems (as DropDownList).

So maybe some asynchronous Ajax solution would be better?

Does there anything useful exist which I can use for simple selection but with lots of elements?

I would be very glad of your advice.

Comment: I don't know if anything from the Ajax Control Toolkit is suitable for you. I use the jQuery UI autocomplete widget or the select2 jQuery plugin.

Comment: Perhaps a TextBox with autocomplete?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854358/how-to-make-an-autocomplete-textbox-in-asp-net

Comment: You can try RadDropDownList (Virtual Scrolling - http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dropdownlist/examples/functionality/virtualscrolling/defaultcs.aspx) or RadCombobox with enabled Load-on-Demand http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx.

Comment: @Rumen Jekov: Looks very useful but its not free?

Comment: If you are looking for a good free dropdownlist you can evaluate Kendo UI - http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index

Answer (score 0):

1) Add a dropdown with A-Z, or links from A-Z which will filter your results alphabetically giving you much less to deal with.

2) Also, instead of using a dropdown to display your filtered results, you could use a gridview with paging. if the results are in alphabetical order this will make it much easier for a user to find what they are looking for.