# SQL database filtered search box with auto complete in ASP.NET webforms

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, autocomplete, webforms

Building a website with a back end SQL database. The database holds 571 houses with information about each. I want to add a search feature to the site. I have googled a lot the past couple of days but there are no good step by step guides available for what I am looking for. I want to search for a house by name and as I start typing I want an extender to display with results from the database and when I select one I want it to bring me to a separate aspx page for the specific house and display all the information for it. I have came here as a last resort because google has not been helpful so far.

**Search**

[image]

**House Information page**

[image]

**Database**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Houses] (
    [Id]          NCHAR (10)     NOT NULL,
    [Name]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Townland]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Near]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Status]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Built]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Families]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Images]      IMAGE          NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Houses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Try google something like "using ajax to retrieve data from database" surely you'll get and idea.

Comment: done that all the links use a web service which I don't want

Comment: @ProDiablo is your application always going to run on the same computer where the user is accessing the site?

Comment: no the company is going to host the site locally on their servers

Comment: So basically you want an autocomplete feature for your textbox. [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854358/how-to-make-an-autocomplete-textbox-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is auto-suggetion text box.

Just googled for auto suggestion text box and tadda you will find lot of resources for that.[One of auto suggestion example](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-AJAX-AutoSuggest-TextBox-Example.aspx)